# Notepad++ won't run the content in google Chrome

Tags: notepad++

I'm a beginner in learning PHP. 
The code that i have written in Notepad++ is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
echo "This is a test";
?> 

</body>
</html>
```

I saved this code in my folder as test.html and I tried to run from Google Chrome or Internet Explorer but those don't show the content.

How can i fix this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a PHP code, not HTML. You need to run it on PHP-capable server, examples for beginners being [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) or [WTServer](https://wtserver.wtriple.com/).

Answer (score 0):

As Hex said before, you need to have a web server running on your system.

Additionally, you'll need to rename the file to "test.php" instead.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server-side programming/scripting language. No browser is capable of parsing and evaluating server-side code. You should set up a web server using a full blown stack, as Hex mentioned XAMPP.

Place your code in a file named foo.php in XAMPP's root folder (eg. C:\xampp\www), then point your browser to `http://localhost/foo.php`